# download a pdf file on clicking the link button in classic Asp

Tags: asp-classic

I am working in classic Asp. I want to download a pdf file on clicking the link button. My file is in ("../aa/file.pdf"). with this file path can't we download. Can anyone share me a code to do so ?

Comment: Does the path exist?  It doesn't look like you're having trouble downloading a PDF, it looks like you're having trouble building links in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You code doesn't look like it is including the full path of the file on your download link. The link needs the full path, e.g.

```
response.write "<a href=""c:\DownloadPFRelatedForms\Withdrawal\" & Server.UrlEncode(ObjFile.Name) & """>download</a>
```

or use a virtual directory mapped to the location of your pdf files and have a direct link, e.g.

```
response.write "<a href=""" & Server.UrlEncode(ObjFile.Name) & """>download</a>
```